Populating Nested References in Mongoose Returns Only IDs Instead of Full Documents
// backend\models\Playlist.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const playlistSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    videos: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Video' }],
    userId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Playlist', playlistSchema);

// backend\models\Video.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  userId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
  username: { type: String, required: true },
  comment: { type: String, required: true },
  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
});

const videoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  description: String,
  url: String,
  uploadDate: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
  uploader: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
  likes: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
  comments: [commentSchema],
  cloudinary_id: { type: String, required: true },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Video', videoSchema);

// backend\models\User.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
});

userSchema.pre('save', async function (next) {
  if (this.isModified('password')) {
    this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 10);
  }
  next();
});

userSchema.methods.comparePassword = function (password) {
  return bcrypt.compare(password, this.password);
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

The Playlist Modal has reference to Video Modal, The Video Modal has reference to User Modal, but I am receiving only the video id's present in Playlist Modal, not the entire video document.
This is how I am accessing using API:
router.get('/playlist/:id/videos', authMiddleware, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const playlist = await Playlist.findById(req.params.id)
            .populate({
                path: 'videos',
                populate: { path: 'uploader' }
            });
        if (playlist.userId.toString() !== req.userData.userId) {
            return res.status(403).json({ message: 'Forbidden' });
        }
        res.json(playlist.videos);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: err.message });
    }
});

I tried noticing that I have implemented populate in other APIs & it works fine, but not here.

Please show a video document and a playlist document - Only the relevant keys.

Provided the relevant keys for a video document and a playlist document in my schema

You have edited the question to such an extent that your original question and code has now gone. I also think it was an actual document that was requested not your schema. However, your schema is important so leave it in the question. You now need to edit the question to include your original code showing how you are attempting to do the populate and add sample document.

Sorry for the vagueness in my response. The part "Only the relevant keys" should have been made clear as "actual documents with the relevant keys and its values". Surely schema would be helpful as you now made it included.

@jQueeny, My Bad, should have double checked. Now I have included necessary details. Ready to add any other that's important to debug the issued.

@WedothebestforYou, Yeah schema is already included, somewhere the error seems to lie here

Please see the code below. The same three schema definitions have been used over here. And then created a test playlist. The retrieval code is also the same used in the original question. Please see the output, the video document now is populated.
Request please pay close attention to the code at the line “setting video reference”. This could be the potential line to be checked against your code. As you know, this line sets the reference with the Video document, the link between the playlist document and the video document. Since the schema definitions and the find statement are found working fine as it is, this line would be the most potential one to review.
If it turns out that the above mentioned line is also correct in your code, please repeat the test with a new set of documents - create a new user, a new video document against the new user, and a new playlist against the new video.
// MongoDB: 7.0.2
// Mongoose : 8.3.2
// Node.js v21.6.0.
// populateissue.mjs

import mongoose, { Schema } from 'mongoose';

main().catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
});

async function main() {
  await mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/myapp');

  const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
  });

  const Usermodel = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
  await Usermodel.deleteMany();

  const commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    userId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    username: { type: String, required: true },
    comment: { type: String, required: true },
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  });

  const videoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    description: String,
    url: String,
    uploadDate: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now,
    },
    uploader: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    likes: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
    comments: [commentSchema],
    cloudinary_id: { type: String, required: true },
  });

  const Videomodel = mongoose.model('Video', videoSchema);
  await Videomodel.deleteMany();

  const playlistSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    videos: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Video' }],
    userId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
  });

  const Playlistmodel = mongoose.model('Playlist', playlistSchema);
  await Playlistmodel.deleteMany();

  const userdoc = new Usermodel({
    username: 'somename',
    password: 'somepassword',
  });

  const videodoc = new Videomodel({
    title: 'someTitle',
    uploader: userdoc._id,
    cloudinary_id: 'someId',
  });

  const playlistdoc = new Playlistmodel({
    name: 'someName',
    videos: videodoc._id,  // setting video reference
    userId: userdoc._id, // kept it the same as uploader since it is a test data
  });

  await userdoc.save();
  await videodoc.save();
  await playlistdoc.save();

  const playlistdocs = await Playlistmodel.findById(playlistdoc._id).populate({
    path: 'videos',
    populate: { path: 'uploader' },
  });

  console.log(playlistdocs);
  console.log(playlistdocs.videos);
}

// output
{
  _id: new ObjectId('6629c3f3450ae04736c1877e'),
  name: 'someName',
  videos: [
    {
      _id: new ObjectId('6629c3f3450ae04736c1877d'),
      title: 'someTitle',
      uploader: [Object],
      likes: [],
      cloudinary_id: 'someId',
      uploadDate: 2024-04-25T02:46:11.929Z,
      comments: [],
      __v: 0
    }
  ],
  userId: new ObjectId('6629c3f3450ae04736c1877c'),
  __v: 0
}
[
  {
    _id: new ObjectId('6629c3f3450ae04736c1877d'),
    title: 'someTitle',
    uploader: {
      _id: new ObjectId('6629c3f3450ae04736c1877c'),
      username: 'somename',
      password: 'somepassword',
      __v: 0
    },
    likes: [],
    cloudinary_id: 'someId',
    uploadDate: 2024-04-25T02:46:11.929Z,
    comments: [],
    __v: 0
  }
]


Thank you for the assistance. repeating the test with a new set of documents as you suggested resolved the issue. A minor problem can indeed cause significant distress.
